# Modify a random variable to make its range Borel?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis

Let $X: \Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ be a random variable. Is it always possible to modify it (i.e. change the value of $X$ on a subset of $\Omega$ of zero measure) so that the range of $X$ is a Borel set?

This is related to the following question: we know that $E(Y|X)$ can be written as a function of $X$, i.e. $E(Y|X)=\varphi(X)$ for some $\varphi: {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. Is $\varphi$ (Borel) measurable? We can prove this if we know $X$ has Borel range.

I guess the answers might be negative, will there be (easy) counterexamples? Can we add some assumptions to make the conclusion true?

Comment: If you are interested in probability you may assume that the measure is complete (each subset of a set of measure zero  is measurable). In many cases $\Omega$ will contain a set of measure zero with cardinal the continuum. Then you may modify the random variable in this measure zero set so that the range is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The function $\varphi$ in your question is not unique (since the equality $E(Y \mid X)=\varphi(X)$ can only be expected to hold a.s.), and it is indeed true that you can always choose it to be Borel measurable.  That should be part of the statement - it would be a pretty useless theorem if this were not true.

Comment: The related result is true even without the need to modify the conditional expectation (i. e., for any choice of one), see e. g. Lemma 1.13 in Kallenberg, Foundations of modern probability.

Comment: The relevant condition on a probability measure is being *perfect*, a notion due to Gnedenko and Kolmogorov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $(\Omega, {\mathcal F}, P)$ itself is a Lebesgue space, so it can be realized as a Polish space equipped with the completion of the Borel sets. If $X$ is a random variable, it can be changed on a set of measure zero to be a Borel measurable function. (This is an easy consequence of [1]). Thus we may assume $X$ itself is Borel measurable.

The class of analytic sets is closed under   direct images  by Borel functions, see e.g. Proposition 1.4 in [2], or [3].
Finally, any analytic set is universaly measurable [3], so $X(\Omega)$ differs from a Borel set $B$ on a set $A$ of zero measure with respect to the push-forward $\mu:=PX^{-1}$, that is $B=X(\Omega) \setminus  A$. Thus if $X^*$ is obtained from $X$ by changing it to map $X^{-1}(A)$ to one point in $B$, then $X^*(\Omega)=B$.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem

[2]  [https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~dominique.lecomte/Chapitres/6-Analytic%20and%20co-analytic%20sets.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Edominique.lecomte/Chapitres/6-Analytic%20and%20co-analytic%20sets.pdf)

[3] Kechris, A. Descriptive set theory, Springer.